# Nivo slider issue in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, nivo-slider

Images do not load/show when I add them to Nivo Slider. The log message states

```
Failed to create style directory: public://styles/square_thumbnail/public
```

Could any one help me out of this??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have write permissions on your `/public_html/sites/default/files` folder (chmod 755). You can do it by changing folder chmods by your FTP Client.

Also check `http://yoursite.com/admin/reports/status` if there are any notifications about wrong directory permissions.

Comment: ya thanks alot it works. i have changed the permission to 777 now it works fine thanks again...